# Using a FOR loop to iterate through JSON data and create a list of a specified property('name'), cannot create another SINGLE element referencing prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am currently using some JSON data as my resources.

I am iterating through the JSON data to find the property "name" and then add the name property to an option element within a select element.

```
function addOptionsToSelect(obj){
    const names = obj['data'];
    for(let i=0; i< names.length; i++){
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = names[i].viewName;
    allAccounts.push(names[i].viewName);
    select.appendChild(option);
    }
    addId(obj);
}
```

allAccounts is an empty array.

Within the JSON data, there are multiple properties within an object, there are over 100 objects, each object has "name" and "id", the desired output is, now that I have pushed all of my name properties my option element, when the option is selected, ID should be reflected elsewhere in a p element in correlation with that selected name option.

So, in simple terms, if the name in option is 'name 1', then in some p element below, the id should be 1.

I attempted to create this output by creating an empty array 'allAccount' that pushes all the name properties to it.

I then created a function addId()

```
function addId(obj){
    const data = obj['data'];
    for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i].viewName === allAccounts[i]){
            googleId.textContent = data[i]['googleId'];
        }
    }
}
```

I fed it both the json data and the elements in array, it compares the values within both and if it finds a match it should add the ID of that match to the p element with the id googleId.

Now as you can see the problem is because its in a for loop, and the id ends up being much higher than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing the JSON data to know how the structure is, I'm assuming that it is something like the JSON in the snippet below.

Then just add the id to the value of the option. Then add an change event listener to the select element and put that value in the p element. You can even utilize the html5 dataset to store and retrieve data from the select.

```js
const jsonData = `[
    {
        "CustomerID": 1,
        "CustomerName": "Tailspin Toys (Head Office)",
        "PhoneNumber": "(308) 555-0100",
        "FaxNumber": "(308) 555-0101",
        "DeliveryAddressLine1": "Shop 38",
        "DeliveryAddressLine2": "1877 Mittal Road",
        "DeliveryPostalCode": "90410"
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2,
        "CustomerName": "Tailspin Toys (Sylvanite, MT)",
        "PhoneNumber": "(406) 555-0100",
        "FaxNumber": "(406) 555-0101",
        "DeliveryAddressLine1": "Shop 245",
        "DeliveryAddressLine2": "705 Dita Lane",
        "DeliveryPostalCode": "90216"
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 3,
        "CustomerName": "Tailspin Toys (Peeples Valley, AZ)",
        "PhoneNumber": "(480) 555-0100",
        "FaxNumber": "(480) 555-0101",
        "DeliveryAddressLine1": "Unit 217",
        "DeliveryAddressLine2": "1970 Khandke Road",
        "DeliveryPostalCode": "90205"
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 4,
        "CustomerName": "Tailspin Toys (Medicine Lodge, KS)",
        "PhoneNumber": "(316) 555-0100",
        "FaxNumber": "(316) 555-0101",
        "DeliveryAddressLine1": "Suite 164",
        "DeliveryAddressLine2": "967 Riutta Boulevard",
        "DeliveryPostalCode": "90152"
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 5,
        "CustomerName": "Tailspin Toys (Gasport, NY)",
        "PhoneNumber": "(212) 555-0100",
        "FaxNumber": "(212) 555-0101",
        "DeliveryAddressLine1": "Unit 176",
        "DeliveryAddressLine2": "1674 Skujins Boulevard",
        "DeliveryPostalCode": "90261"
    }
]`;

const sel = document.createElement(`select`);
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

data.forEach(element => {
  const opt = document.createElement(`option`);
  opt.value = element.CustomerID
  opt.textContent = element.CustomerName
  opt.dataset.phoneNumber = element.PhoneNumber
  opt.dataset.deliveryPostalCode = element.DeliveryPostalCode
  sel.appendChild(opt);
});

sel.addEventListener(`change`,event=>{
  const select = event.target;
  const val = select.value;
  const opt = select.querySelector(`[value="${val}"]`);
  const html = `CustomerID = ${select.value}
    <br>PhoneNumber = ${opt.dataset.phoneNumber}
    <br>DeliveryPostalCode = ${opt.dataset.deliveryPostalCode}`;
  document.querySelector(`#some-p-element`).innerHTML = html;
});

document.querySelector(`body`).prepend(sel);
```

```html
<p id="some-p-element"/>
```